# How to Generate Visual Studio 2008 C# solution on fly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

We are planning to implement a simulator generator program that will generate C# solution. Does there exist any object model for Visual Studio 2008 for this. Another option is custom project template i guess but i would prefer first one. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Visual Studio automation, it's called DTE. But if this is all you want, then just create a solution by hand, because it's a simple text file, and a csproj is a simple XML.

Comment: I would be generating code via code dom for the new project. thats why i would rather want object model

Answer (score 1):

To create a new, empty solution, the easiest way is via the Visual Studio automation. Look at the [Solution.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.open%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method.
There is another way, via the [IVsSolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) interface. You could do it like this:

```
var solution = (IVsSolution)GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));
ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(solution.CreateSolution(solutionPath, solutionName, 0));
```